# Is there a database of granted and declined funding proposals available with abstracts?

Tags: publications, funding, databases

I´m looking for a database of granted and declined scientific funding proposals. The applications should contain an identifier of the subject as well as the semantic components of the application and be available for download. The area of applications does not matter.
I have already found the website of the National Science Foundation (NSF). In my opinion, there are only the granted applications. In addition, I find in the database only the application, but not the announcement.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

Proposals are usually submitted with the expectation of confidentiality. A database of proposals by a funder is therefore unlikely.

Some people choose to publish their grant proposals at time of submissions (me included; [RIO Journal](https://riojournal.com/) is the only place I know that does this).

Comment: that would hold for unfounded proposals.  In many countries funding agencies will publish details of the *funded* proposal.

Answer (score 2):

There is an attempt to collate this sort of information at https://www.ogrants.org/. So far its quite small, but could grow over time.

Answer (score 1):

The DFG (Deutsche Forschungsgemeinschaft) has a database of funded proposals as well: http://www.dfg.de/en/funded_projects/index.html.

I second Chris Hartgerink: There can not be a data base of rejected proposals due to confidentiality issues.